# need help for rewrite rule to make url clean and seo friendly?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo

Current pattern is `http://example.com/questions.php?qcid=25&name=java`  and I want to make it `http://example.com/25/java` where **qcid** must be **[0-9]** and **name** must be **readable and encoded**. If it comprise of more than 1 word then **'-' hyphen** must be there between them. For example **object-oriented**.

Comment: The qcid bit of this is pretty easy but the name being readable and encoded?  I'm not really sure what you mean there.  You might have to handle that bit in code.

Comment: for example  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488558/need-help-for-rewrite-rule-to-make-url-clean-and-seo-friendly

Comment: you just linked to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)(?!(.css)|(.js))$ questions.php?qcid=$1&name=$2 [NC]
```

In php, you'll need to capture name and strip the hyphens and fix the caps if needed.  As an example, lets say we want the name to be lower camel cased:

```
$_GET['name'] = "this-is-a-test-name";

$name = '';
$exploded = explode('-',$_GET['name']);
foreach($exploded as $piece) {
    $name .= ucfirst($piece);
}
// If you have PHP >= 5.3
// $name = lcfirst($name);
// Otherwise
$name{0} = strtolower($name{0});

echo $name;
```

Comment: @mkat I added a negative lookahead to exclude css and js.  You can add other extensions as appropriate.

Comment: ohh i made big mistake i didn't append baseurl... thank you buddy :)

Comment: @mkat No problem.  I also added a suggestion to handle your name expression.  You'll probably have to change it to suit your purpose, but it should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

This will take any url starting with numbers, then slash, then anything and convert them like shown above. However if you require some sort of url encoding/decoding, you'll have to handle that bit in your questions.php script

```
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/(.+) /questions.php?qcid=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: hy it wroks but doesn't load css and js files and my ajax functionality ,too.

Comment: what are the paths of the css/js, and are they expected to be redirected too? Please post additional details if there are additional constraints to work within

Comment: ########## Begin - No directory listings
## Note: +FollowSymlinks may cause problems and you might have to remove it
IndexIgnore *
Options +FollowSymLinks All -Indexes
########## End - No directory listings

#with out WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#disables PHP ERRORS
php_flag display_errors off

# removes index.php from url
RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ / [L,R=301,NC]

Comment: css/js in root/(folder) would not be affected by this rewrite. Neither would the rules you just added in the comment.

Comment: ohh i made big mistake i didn't append baseurl... thank you buddy :)